# Create example files in module Python 3

Tags: python, module, package

I am developing a Python package and I'd like to add some examples to it.
My goal is to be able to execute them by doing something like:
`python3 -m package.examples.example_file_1`

And the example1 will be executed

However, I can't figure out how to do so.
This is my file structure:

```sh
Package
 |─ examples
 |   |─ __init__.py
 |   |─ example_file_1.py
 |   |─ example_file_2.py
 |   |─ example_file_3.py
 |─ __init__.py
 |─ package_file_1.py
 |─ package_file_2.py
 |─ package_file_3.py
 |─ package_file_4.py
```

When I run the `python3 -m package.examples.example_file_1` command, I get this:

```
/usr/bin/python3.8: Error while finding module specification for 'package.examples.example_file_1' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package.examples')
```

Solution: In my setup.py file I was using `setuptools.find_packages()` instead of `setuptools.find_namespace_packages()` which is what is supposed to be used in python 3.3+

Comment: You probably need to add an __init__.py file to each folder: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for

Comment: @Mike67 I have tried adding an \_\_init__.py file but it hasn't worked

Comment: Oh wait I found the problem. In my setup.py file I was using `find_packages` instead of `find_namespace_packages`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `find_namespace_packages` instead of `find_packages` should do it.